# JpaRepository count distinct is not working as expected

Tags: java, scala, count, spring-data-jpa, distinct

For some strange reason Jpa generated queries are not being generated as expected. Using jpa I wrote the following query in my repository:

My Object

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  var id: Long = _

  @Column(name = "global_event_id", nullable = false)
  var globalEventId: Long = _

  @Column(name = "date_created")
  @NotNull
  @Type(`type` = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
  var dateCreated: DateTime = _

  @Column(name = "ip", nullable = false)
  var ip: String = _

  @Column(name = "email")
  var email: java.lang.String = _
```

My Repository

```
trait RequestRepository extends JpaRepository[Request, java.lang.Long] {    
def countDistinctIpByGlobalEventIdGreaterThanAndDateCreatedGreaterThanAndEmail(@Param("globalEventId") globalEventId: Long, @Param("dateCreated") dateCreated: DateTime, @Param("email") email: String): java.lang.Long
}
```

Im expecting the following query to be generated

```
SELECT count(distinct(ip)) FROM rule_request WHERE global_event_id > ? AND email = ? AND date_created >= ?
```

but instead the following is being generated which is obviously wrong (**id** instead of **ip** for starters)

```
select distinct count(request0_.id) as col_0_0_ from rule_request request0_ where request0_.global_event_id>? and request0_.date_created>? and request0_.email=?
```

Im using:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
```

Any ideas why please?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use query derivation beyond its capabilities.

`distinct` is used exclusively for obtaining distinct results.

`count` always effectively counts all rows by just counting the ids.

There is no way to make query derivation to make a `count( distinct <expression>)` or even a `count( <expression>)`.

Use a `@Query` annotation instead.

Comment: Thanks! That what I had to do infact.